# Use of Tealium to track multiple on-page tags for each Google Analytics Content Grouping

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, analytics, tealium

I'm in the middle of researching this and can't find a ton on the exact subject, so I was hoping one of you fine people might have the answer. Essentially, I'm trying to set up Content Groupings in Google Analytics for a network of WordPress installations where each blog post can have n number of tags and categories.

The Content Grouping would be something like Home Page, Posts, Pages.

Under the "Posts" Content Grouping, let's say I have a Movie post type that can track different genres (Romance and Comedy, or Science Fiction and Horror, or Action, Science Fiction and Horror, or even just Romance at times). I'd want to inject those into the page (easy enough to do), then loop through them and set them under the Posts content grouping for that particular page load.

However, the client is using Tealium for Google Analytics tracking, which adds a layer of abstraction to things. So the question is really a two-parter:

1. How would I fire off multiple tags for a given Content Grouping on a given page load so they're useful within Google Analytics?
2. How would I use Tealium to do that?

Tealium does offer up some documentation on Converting GUA Tracking to Tealium Tracking, like so:

Example GUA code snippet for event tracking

```
ga('send', {
    hitType        : 'event',
    eventCategory  : 'Videos',
    eventAction    : 'play',
    eventLabel     : 'Fall Campaign'
});
```

Converting to Tealium style by setting the `ga_events` variable with the GUA event fields:

```
utag.link({
    ga_events: [{
        eventCategory : 'Videos',
        eventAction   : 'play',
        eventLabel    : 'Fall Campaign'
    }]
});
```

This is exactly the kind of Conversion Documentation I am looking for. However, it does not cover my use-case, which seems to require multiple calls to something like:

```
ga('set', 'Posts', 'Action');
ga('set', 'Posts', 'Science Fiction');
ga('set', 'Posts', 'Horror');
```

How would I do this (successfully) using Tealium?

Thanks in advance for any feedback or help anyone is willing to offer!

**Edit**

https://megalytic.com/blog/adding-google-analytics-content-group-tracking-to-a-wordpress-theme-using-google-tag-manager

This link talks about what I'm attempting to do, but using Google Tag Manager as opposed to Tealium. There is a lot of overlap there, so I'll try to dive in and find the equivalent process, but I'd still appreciate any help someone can provide!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'd be best off just writing your own custom javascript to manually fire your google analytics events. Could you use a custom container as described [here](https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/iQ-Tag-Management/When-to-use-Tealium-Custom-Tags/ta-p/14018)? You can remove the script src if you don't need to load anything.   You should then be able to have that container run on every page load.

Answer (score 0):

Tealium works by mapping the variables in each tag.

First of all you need mapping the content grouping in your Google Analytics tag.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Then you can add the variable into the `utag.link`:

```
utag.link({
    ga_events: [{
        eventCategory : 'Videos',
        eventAction   : 'play',
        eventLabel    : 'Fall Campaign'
    }],
    Post : 'Action'
});
```